# Send HTTP Post with default browser with C#

Tags: c#, http, browser, post

I am wondering if it is possible to send POST data with the default browser of a computer in C#.

Here is the situation. My client would like the ability to have their C# application open their browser and send client information to a webform. This webform would be behind a login screen. The assumption from the application side is that once the client data is sent to the login screen, the login screen would pass that information onto the webform to prepopulate it. This would be done over HTTPS and the client would like this to be done with a POST and not a GET as client information would be sent as plain text.

I have found some wonderful solutions that do POSTS and handle the requests. As an example
http://geekswithblogs.net/rakker/archive/2006/04/21/76044.aspx

So the TL;DR version of this would be

1) Open Browser

2) Open some URL with POST data

Thanks for your help,

Paul

Comment: @John, What kind of virus would want to do this?  If I was writing a virus, the last thing I would want to do would be POST data in plain view when I could just do it the easy way behind the scenes.

Comment: @Brad, it's not a virus, as such, but it would certainly be a security hole.

Comment: A rogue app that submits something assuming someone's existing session

Comment: @John, I don't think that's what he is asking, is it?  I read this as, the program does a POST, and then the user is prompted to login, initiating the session, and then that POST data is validated later.  Must like if I clicked a protected area on a site and get sent to the login page, only to be redirect to where I was going after logging in.  Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Brad. That is exactly what I want to do. The posted data is used to prefil a form that user will see. They will then submit it and the webapp will validate the data. The only thing is the form is behind a login screen

Comment: @Paul, then this entirely depends on what happens server-side.  Otherwise, yes you are indeed hijacking a browser session.  If server-side, form data can be held onto while a user logs in, and then prefilled, then what I posted will in fact work just fine.

Answer (score 5):

I've handled a similar situation once by generating an HTML page on the fly with a form setup with hidden values for everything.  There was a bit of Javascript on the page so that when it loaded, it would submit the form, therefore posting the data as necessary.

I suspect this method would work for you.

1. Generate a dictionary of fields and values
2. Generate an HTML page with the Javascript to automatically submit when page is loaded
3. Write page to a temp location on disk
4. Launch default browser with that page

Remember though that POST data is sent plaintext as well.  POST is generally the way to go for more than a couple fields, as you can fit in more data (2048 byte limit on URLs) and that your user has a friendly URL to see in their browser.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is sent as plain text when you use SSL, it is encrypted.  Unless you set what the default browser is (IE, Firefox, Chrome, etc), then you'll have to figure out what the default browser is and use its API to do this work (if it's possible).

What would probably be must faster and more efficient would be to open the default browser by invoking a URL with Start Process and pass the information on the query string (this is doing a GET instead of a POST, which I know isn't what you're asking for).

The response from the server could be a redirect, and the redirect could send down the filled-out form (storing the values in session or something similar).

That way the complexity is pushed to the website and not the windows application, which should be easier to update if something goes wrong.

HTH

Comment: Yes I believe that is what the intent will be (sorry some of the details are being sorted out now and I am figuring out the logistics). So once the data is sent to whatever page, login/webform/etc, I do not need to worry. It's the page that will do the work for me. 

I guess the next question is, if it's over HTTPS do we really need to worry if it's a GET or a POST? Does it matter that client data is in the query string?

Comment: @Paul: Not unless you're worried about the end-user easily seeing the data.

Comment: @Steven Sudit. Thanks for the help. No I am not worried as they would be seeing this information in the original app. Basically they want to break it down to this.


1) View data in original app


2) Press button


3) Send data to webapp.    



I believe I have enough info here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you compile your logic in C# and then call it from PowerShell? From PowerShell you can [very easily automate Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337896.aspx). This is IE only but you might be able to also use [WaitnN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score -1):

Anything you put at the end of the URL counts as the querystring, which is what GET fills. It is more visible than the POSTed data in the body, but no more secure with regard to a sniffer.

So, in short, no.

Comment: This doesn't address the question at all.

Comment: He does mention that post will occur over HTTPS.

Comment: To clarify, POST data is no more secure than having the data in the query string (As in if I use a GET)?

Comment: @Paul: If you can see what's going over the wire, the POST data is just as visible. And if you can't, due to HTTPS, then it's just as invisible. The real difference is that the user can see it in the URL.

Comment: @John: It addresses it by explaining why what the question is asking for is not a good idea.

Comment: At first read it sounded to me like POST was a requirement of the endpoint, but after re-reading I see how it could be interpreted that he thought POST was more secure, making your answer relevant.

Comment: POST is more secure if and only if you are using SSL

Comment: @Robert: Is this conclusion based on the idea that the URL will be exposed in the client's cache or some intermediate proxy but the body won't?

Comment: with ssl, the URL & querystring are sent in the clear but the body of request & response are encrypted.

Comment: @Robert: With SSL, every byte is encrypted; nothing is sent in the clear. See http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/758002.html

Comment: @Robert, you're not entirely wrong: a bad proxy can compromise the URL, as can a bad web client. Even with SSL, it's best to keep passwords out of the URL.